# MVVM INotifyPropertyChanged in dynamically changed arrays

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In my hobby project I have the following situation:

I'm using C#, WPF, MVVM (well MVVM: try to)

I load a binary file with information and store it in a list of (unsigned) bytes. I have a class hierarchy referencing to specific locations in the list. My application changes sometimes the class hierarchy (and the referencing bytes), but also sometimes bytes directly (like copying a range).

I have windows in where I have bound a list view to the mapped structure.

When changing properties in the classes I use the INotifyPropertyChanged as it should be used in MVVM. However, I have problems when changing the bytes directly. Currently I'm using manual Update methods but it's getting very messy.

Is there some kind of solution for this?

Also the list of bytes can be like 45 MB of data. If I set a notification on the list would that mean that for every byte change I get a notify on all observers? Meaning when I would copy e.g. 10KB of bytes one by one, and I would have like 100 observer functions (handling property changes) in 1 million updates? That would be a performance killer.

Or can I also say something like: now update class X (i.e. all property changes inside a class). I cannot use the set property function because the values already have been changed while copying bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing your bytes in a list (`List<byte>`) then you could simpley change the type of the list to [`ObservableCollection<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and your code will run with nearly no change. Then you can get rid of manual updates.

But if you hold the data in a byte array (`byte[]`), again the best option is changing it to [`ObservableCollection<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), but you may have to change some of your codes using the colletion.

If you have special cases to handle, another option may be to create your own data structure, implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). But this is lots of code to write.

Comment: The last method seems the best; somethign similar as I am using now I think (but get's a mess easily).

Answer (score 2):

You could do your binding to an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Do you mean the complete list of bytes? That would be all items ... not sure if that would be a good idea. That means an update of all classes and all properties.